# Clock mismatch between webserver & database

Tags: django, postgresql, datetime, amazon-web-services

I notice a timestamp mismatch between my webserver (Amazon EC2) & database (Amazon RDS running PostgreSQL). They are off by a few seconds.

There are some entries that are created in the database with a timestamp (using SQL `current_timestamp`). The server reads these entries and compares the timestamp with its own clock (using Django `timezone.now()`) to select entries newer than 'x' minutes.

This mismatch leads to inconsistenct data. What's a good approach to make my code fault tolerant to clock mismatch between different machines. Should I remove the `timezone.now()` function on server side and instead read the timestamp from the database instead? This will add a slight overhead of database access, but the timestamp would be consistent across multiple web servers.

Or, is there a better way to keep the 2 machines synchronized?

Comment: If you are using linux machine, you can enable ntpd to keep your clocks synced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mismatch of few seconds is way too much. Are you using NTP on your server to sync clock to some reference server? I assume that Amazon RDS does keep clock synchronized, so I suspect you can do something on your EC2 instance via NTP to reduce the skew.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much you can do if you are using RDS, so I would take the database query approach. Also maybe you are experiencing this same [bug](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=594624)?